# factory girl multiple has_many through's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I need to create some factories that are made of multiple has many through's

Here are my models

```
Topic
  has_many :plan_topics
  has_many :plans, :through => :plan_topics

PlanTopic
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :topic

Plan
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :members, :through => :subscriptions
  has_many :plan_topics
  has_many :topics, :through => :plan_topics

Subscription
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :plan

Member
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :plans, :through => :subscriptions
```

Here is what I have

```
Factory.define :topic do |topic|
  topic.name "Operations"
end

Factory.define :plan do |plan|
  plan.title "A test Finance plan"
  plan.price "200"
end

Factory.define :plan_topic do |plan_topic|
  plan_topic.topic {|topic| topic.association(:topic)}
  plan_topic.plan {|plan| plan.association(:plan)}
end
```

What I would like to do is this - Factory(:member_with_subscription)

```
Factory.define :member_with_subscription do |subscription|
  subscription.association(:plan_with_topic)
  subscription.association(:member)
end
```

Is there a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using `after_build` callback to set all required dependencies. For example:

```
Factory.define :member_with_subscription, :class => 'Member' do |m|
  m.after_build do |member|
    member.subscriptions << Factory.build(:subscription)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I do it slightly differently, and this way might be slightly easier to understand:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :member_with_description do
    after(:build) do |member|
      member.subscriptions << FactoryGirl.build(:subscription)
    end
  end 
end
```