# FactoryGirl 3.x has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I've seen a couple examples of the older syntax, but I can't find an example using the new 3.x syntax (one such older example: [factory girl multiple has_many through's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259074/factory-girl-multiple-has-many-throughs)).

Models

```
class RawPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :position_translations
  has_many :specific_positions, through: :position_translations
end

class SpecificPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :position_translations
  has_many :raw_positions, through: :position_translations
end

class PositionTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :raw_position
  belongs_to :specific_position
end
```

Factories

```
factory :raw_poisition_multiple, class: RawPosition do
    raw_input "WR/QB"
    sport_type_id 5

    after_create do |a|
      #a.specific_positions.create({specific_position: "WR"})
      #a.specific_positions.create({specific_position: "QB"})
      FactoryGirl.create(:specific_position, raw_position: a)
      FactoryGirl.create(:qb_specific_position, raw_position: a)
    end
  end

factory :specific_position do
    specific_position "WR"
  end

factory :qb_specific_position do
    specific_position "QB"
end
```

Spec

```
describe "WR/QB" do
      before do
        @player.player_dict['POS'] = "WR/QB"
        FactoryGirl.create(:raw_poisition_multiple)

        @player.clean_position(@player_to_team_history)
      end
 ....
 end
```

If I uncomment the lines from the `raw_position_multiple` factory and comment out the `FactoryGirl` lines in the `after_create` block, things work fine.  I'd just like the ability to use a factory to create the associations.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past a similar issue by reloading the root model after creating the associations.  In your example, that would mean adding:

```
a.reload
```

to the end of your `after_create` block.

Comment: Absolute lifesaver! spent hours trying to figure out why the other end of the association wasn't working correctly!